# Python logging does not produce newline after each log (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, logging

I have used the same Python script on Windows which worked fine and produced several logs during each time it was run. The problem is when I ran the script on Linux the logging produced all of the logs onto one line.

I  have tried \n in different places such as in the formatter, in each line itself.

This is how the logging is set up:

```
# This is the setup of the logging system for the program.
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Sets the name of the log file to 'login.log'
handler = logging.FileHandler(config.path['logger'])

# Sets up the format of the log file: Time, Function Name, Error Level (e.g. Warning Info, Critical),
# and then the message that follows the format.
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)-5s %(funcName)-20s %(levelname)-10s %(message)s')

handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(handler)

# Sets the lowest level of messages to info.
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

And here is how each log is made:

```
logger.warning('%-15s' % client + ' Failed: Logout Error')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure it isn't your editor that is not rendering `\n` as a newline (and instead expects `\r\n`)?

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html?

Comment: Yeah it worked Thomas, but dont have the rep to upvote!